# Change test logging level for Spring Boot 3

Tags: spring-boot, logging, log-level

Usually if I want to turn the logging on a class up or down, I put this in my `application.yml`:

```
logging:
  level:
    org.foo.Bar: INFO
```

However, that doesn't seem to be working in Spring Boot 3.x (currently using 3.0.4). [The documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.logging.log-levels) says to use quotes and lower-case instead, so I tried e.g. `"info"` but I'm still getting debug logs from `org.foo.Bar` in my unit tests. I also tried both formats in `src/test/resources/application.yml` to see if it was something funky with the test context. Still no luck. What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you show an example of a unit test where this doesn't work?

Comment: :facepalm: I just realized that it's not a Spring Boot test, so of course the Spring properties won't affect it... It's been a long weekend :-)

Comment: Yeah that was what I was assuming as well.